# Local ring of an affine algebraic set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

We define local rings of an irreducible affine algebraic set to be set of all rational functions functions which has a representative such that the denominator of that is non zero when evaluated at that point. Since we are associating rings to every open set of affine variety can we say $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ corresponds to the open set $U= X \cap ( \mathbb{A}^n- \bigcap_{f \in k[x_1,\ldots, x_n],f(p)\neq 0}Z(f))$ which is open in $X$.
Let $V=X \cap (\mathbb{A}^n-Z(I))$ be a neighbourhood of $p$ and $I=\langle f_1, \ldots, f_k\rangle$. then $Z(I)=\cap Z(f_i)$. Hence $\bigcap_{f \in k[x_1,\ldots, x_n],f(p)\neq 0}Z(f))\subset Z(I)=\cap Z(f_i)$, it follows $V\subset U$. It is the smallest neigbourhood, if that makes sense. So, can we say that it represents the "infinitesimal" neighborhood around $p$?

Answer (score 1):

There are significant problems in what you write. For starters:

> $U= X \cap ( \mathbb{A}^n- \bigcap_{f \in k[x_1,\ldots, x_n],f(p)\neq 0}Z(f))$

is just $X$: consider what happens when you take $f$ to be a function nonvanishing on $X$. If we flip the $\bigcap$ to a $\bigcup$, which is eminently more reasonable (remember, going from the variety side to the ideal side is inclusion-reversing, so $\bigcap$ and $\bigcup$ trade places), we run in to the problem that what you get is not generally an open subset of $X$ - consider $X=\Bbb A^1_k$ and $p$ any closed point.

There is sort of a bit of truth to what you write here, though - one can think of the local ring at a point as measuring what happens on a neighborhood of the point which is smaller than any Zariski-open neighborhood. On the other hand, the local ring still sees lots of global information: for instance, if $X$ is a smooth curve and $p$ is a closed point, then $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ determines $X$ up to isomorphism. I would argue that this doesn't deserve the name "infinitesimal neighborhood".

Something that's perhaps closer to an infinitesimal neighborhood is a "formal neighborhood" - this is the completion of $X$ along $p$, which is represented on the ring side by $\widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,p}}$, the completion of $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ along $\mathfrak{m}_p$. This is much more local than $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ - for instance, if $X$ and $Y$ are a varieties that are smooth of dimension $d$ at $p\in X$ and $q\in Y$, then $\widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,p}}\cong \widehat{\mathcal{O}_{Y,q}}\cong k[[x_1,\cdots,x_d]]$.

Comment: I should have been careful. If I write $S=\{f \in k[x_1, \ldots, x_n] | Z(f) \cap X \neq \phi, f(p) \neq 0 \} $ and $ U =X \cap (\mathbb{A}^n - \cap_{f \in S} Z(f) )$, I guess it should work. So, no zariski open set corresponds to $\mathcal {O}_{X,p}$?. Or, $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}= \cap_{U\subset X open}\mathcal{O}_X(U)$

Comment: You still have it wrong - you want to remove every closed subset not containing your point, which must be done by removing the ***union***, not the intersection. To your second point, yes, in general, $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ is not $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ for any open set $U\subset X$.

Comment: Yes, I get it now. Thanks for your time.